# How to plot a function defined in considerable time with Plot3D

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot a function as follows:

```
In[1]:=Psi1[l1_,m1_,l2_,m2_]:=Sqrt[(2*l1+1)/(4*Pi)]*LegendreP[l1,m1,Cos[theta1]]*Sqrt[(2*l2+1)/(4*Pi)]*LegendreP[l2,m2,Cos[theta2]]-Sqrt[(2*l1+1)/(4*Pi)]*LegendreP[l1,m1,Cos[theta2]]*Sqrt[(2*l2+1)/(4*Pi)]*LegendreP[l2,m2,Cos[theta1]]

In[2]:=Den1[l1_,m1_,l2_,m2_]:=1/2*Psi1[l1,m1,l2,m2]^2

In[3]:=Fun1[l1_,m1_,l2_,m2_]:=Integrate[Den1[l1,m1,l2,m2]*Sin[theta1]*Sin[theta2],{theta1,x1,Pi},{phi1,0,2*Pi},{theta2,x2,Pi},{phi2,0,2*Pi}]

In[4]:=Plot3D[Fun1[2,0,1,0],{x1,0,Pi},{x2,0,Pi},PlotRange->All]
```

And:

```
In[5]:=CumDen1[l1_,m1_,l2_,m2_]:=Plot3D[Fun1[l1,m1,l2,m2],{x1,0,Pi},{x2,0,Pi},PlotRange->All]

In[6]:=CumDen1[2,0,1,0]
```

But I've noticed that Mathematica takes more than 60 minutes to plot the function that if it does it in parts:

```
In[7]:=Fun1[2,0,1,0]

In[8]:=Plot3D[%,{x1,0,Pi},{x2,0,Pi},PlotRange->All]
```

With this form, Mathematica graphs the function in less than 60 seconds.

Of course, everything gets too complicated when I want to plot the function for several values of l1 and l2 as follows:

```
In[9]:=Do[If[l1=!=l2,Print[{l1,l2,CumDen1[l1,m1,l2,m2]}]],{l1,0,5},{l2,0,5},{m1,0,0},{m2,0,0}]
```

Is there any way that Mathematica can plot these functions in a considerable time?

Comment: In this case, you might wish to consider memoizing the integration so that it does not have to be done for every point in your plot: `Fun1[l1_, m1_, l2_, m2_] := Fun1[l1, m1, l2, m2] = (* stuff *)`

Comment: Simply putting an `Evaluate` around the function in the plot should help a lot.

Comment: In your def of `Fun1` you're integrating w.r.t. `phi1` and `phi2`. But, as far as I can tell, they don't appear in the integrand. Also, for clarity if nothing else, I would probably write `Psi1` and `Den1` etc. explicitly as functions of the terms you later integrate over (ie. `theta1`, `theta2`, `x1`, `x2`, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TL;DR;

Define

```
int[a_ + b_] = int[a] + int[b]
int[a_] = int[int[a, 1], 2]
int[f_ a_, i_] := f int[a, i] /; FreeQ[f, Indexed[_, i]]
int[f_, i_] := 2 Pi (Pi - Indexed[x, i]) f /; FreeQ[f, Indexed[_, i]]
int[exp[a_?(FreeQ@Indexed[_, i_]) Indexed[\[Theta], i_]], i_] = 
 Integrate[
  Exp[a Indexed[\[Theta], i]], {Indexed[\[Theta], i], Indexed[x, i], 
   Pi}, {Indexed[\[Phi], i], 0, 2*Pi}]
```

and

```
Psi1[l1_, m1_, l2_, m2_] := 
 Sqrt[(2*l1 + 1)/(4*Pi)]*LegendreP[l1, m1, Cos[Indexed[\[Theta], 1]]]*
   Sqrt[(2*l2 + 1)/(4*Pi)]*
   LegendreP[l2, m2, Cos[Indexed[\[Theta], 2]]] - 
  Sqrt[(2*l1 + 1)/(4*Pi)]*
   LegendreP[l1, m1, Cos[Indexed[\[Theta], 2]]]*
   Sqrt[(2*l2 + 1)/(4*Pi)]*
   LegendreP[l2, m2, Cos[Indexed[\[Theta], 1]]] 

Den1[l1_, m1_, l2_, m2_] := 1/2*Psi1[l1, m1, l2, m2]^2 

Fun1[l1_, m1_, l2_, m2_] := 
 Fun1[l1, m1, l2, m2] = 
  Simplify@ExpToTrig[
    int[Expand@
        TrigToExp[
         Den1[l1, m2, l2, m2]*Sin[Indexed[\[Theta], 1]]*
           Sin[Indexed[\[Theta], 2]] /. 
          Sqrt[1 - Cos[Indexed[\[Theta], i_]]^2] :> 
           Sin[Indexed[\[Theta], i]]] /. 
       E^(a_ + b_: 0) :> exp[a] exp[b]] /. exp -> Exp]

Fun1P[l1_, m1_, l2_, m2_] := 
 Fun1[l1, m1, l2, m2] /. {Indexed[x, 1] -> x1, Indexed[x, 2] -> x2}
```

Now plot with:

```
Plot3D[Fun1P[2, 0, 1, 0], {x1, 0, Pi}, {x2, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> All]
```

## Explanation

Apart from memoization/`Evaluate`, we can do a little bit more to speed up this specific function:

First, we look at some typical outputs from `Den1` - you'll notice that the output only consists of products of trigonometric functions and occasionally $\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta_i}$ (which we can simply replace with $\sin\theta_i$ since $0<\theta_i<\pi$). Now we can make our own integration function that is specialized for this type of functions:

To make things a bit easier later, we redefine `Psi1` to use [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed.html) expressions instead of hardcoded names:

```
Psi1[l1_, m1_, l2_, m2_] := 
 Sqrt[(2*l1 + 1)/(4*Pi)]*LegendreP[l1, m1, Cos[Indexed[\[Theta], 1]]]*
   Sqrt[(2*l2 + 1)/(4*Pi)]*
   LegendreP[l2, m2, Cos[Indexed[\[Theta], 2]]] - 
  Sqrt[(2*l1 + 1)/(4*Pi)]*
   LegendreP[l1, m1, Cos[Indexed[\[Theta], 2]]]*
   Sqrt[(2*l2 + 1)/(4*Pi)]*
   LegendreP[l2, m2, Cos[Indexed[\[Theta], 1]]]
```

Next, we define our specialized integral, `int`. First, we make it transparent to addition:

```
int[a_ + b_] = int[a] + int[b]
```

Next, we separate integrals into ones over $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$:

```
int[a_] = int[int[a, 1], 2]
```

where we take `int[f,i]` to mean "integrate `f` over $\theta_1,\phi_1$". Now, we need to pull out constant factors:

```
int[f_ a_, i_] := f int[a, i] /; FreeQ[f, Indexed[_, i]]
```

The [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) (`/;` for short) ensures that the factor we want to pull out does indeed not contain any variable indexed with `i`. Integrals over constants are handled by

```
int[f_, i_] := 2 Pi (Pi - Indexed[x, i]) f /; FreeQ[f, Indexed[_, i]]
```

where the `Condition` ensures once again that we really have a constant. To check how far we got, we can apply it to e.g. `Den1[2, 1, 1, 0]*Sin[Indexed[\[Theta], 1]]*Sin[Indexed[\[Theta], 2]]`:

```
int[Expand@
  TrigToExp[
   Den1[2, 1, 1, 0]*Sin[Indexed[\[Theta], 1]]*
    Sin[Indexed[\[Theta], 2]]]]
```

We apply `Expand` and `TrigToExp` to get terms that are as simple as possible. There are still some square roots left. As mentioned above, we can deal with them using `Sqrt[1 - Cos[Indexed[\[Theta], i_]]^2] :> Sin[Indexed[\[Theta], i]]`:

```
int[Expand@
  TrigToExp[
   Den1[2, 1, 1, 0]*Sin[Indexed[\[Theta], 1]]*
     Sin[Indexed[\[Theta], 2]] /. 
    Sqrt[1 - Cos[Indexed[\[Theta], i_]]^2] :> 
     Sin[Indexed[\[Theta], i]]]]
```

We need some way of separating the exponentials, and since they're automatically combined every time you have a product, we replace them with `exp[x]`: `/. E^(a_ + b_: 0) :> exp[a] exp[b]`. Now we're nearly there:

```
int[Expand@
   TrigToExp[
    Den1[2, 1, 1, 0]*Sin[Indexed[\[Theta], 1]]*
      Sin[Indexed[\[Theta], 2]] /. 
     Sqrt[1 - Cos[Indexed[\[Theta], i_]]^2] :> 
      Sin[Indexed[\[Theta], i]]] /. E^(a_ + b_: 0) :> exp[a] exp[b]]
```

We just need to define `int` for exponential terms:

```
int[exp[a_?(FreeQ@Indexed[_, i_]) Indexed[\[Theta], i_]], i_] = 
 Integrate[
  Exp[a Indexed[\[Theta], i]], {Indexed[\[Theta], i], Indexed[x, i], 
   Pi}, {Indexed[\[Phi], i], 0, 2*Pi}]
```

This applies to expressions of the form $e^{a\cdot\theta_i}$, where we're using our "custom" exponential `exp`. Cleaning up with `Simplify` and `ExpToTrig`, we arrive at our final result (we also replace `exp` with `Exp` again):

```
Simplify@ExpToTrig[
  int[Expand@
      TrigToExp[
       Den1[2, 1, 1, 0]*Sin[Indexed[\[Theta], 1]]*
         Sin[Indexed[\[Theta], 2]] /. 
        Sqrt[1 - Cos[Indexed[\[Theta], i_]]^2] :> 
         Sin[Indexed[\[Theta], i]]] /. 
     E^(a_ + b_: 0) :> exp[a] exp[b]] /. exp -> Exp]
```